# Spring HTML URL View Not Found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a simple question. In a Spring Boot Application I have a controller that works fine:

```
@GetMapping("/mycats")
public String getCats(){
    return "cats.html";
}
```

cats.html is a html file in **resources/static/**

When I change the action URL like this

```
@GetMapping("/mycats/my")
public String getCats(){
    return "cats.html";
}
```

Spring cannot find the html file anymore. I have tried many directory combinations and still no success. I don't use thymeleaf/jsp. Why is that happening?

Comment: I guest that is not good approach if you are using cats.html and you are not using jsp,jsf,etc..  then you can communicate via ajax. Don't use post-back operations

Comment: Single Page Applications do not use post-back operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the context. When you use "mycats" it will look for the page in static directory. but when you use "mycats/my" it will look for the page in the static/my directory. This directory does not exists, so you get a 404 error.

You can make a little change to you controller. You can command it that look for in the previos directory with "../", but you always have to be only on directory deep.

```
@GetMapping("/mycats/my")
public String getCats(){
    return "../cats.html";
}
```

Or from any directory, you can tell spring that looks at root directory with "/"

```
@GetMapping("/mycats/my")
public String getCats(){
    return "/cats.html";
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is like you say. The thing that confused me is that both routes work with thymeleaf and jsp. Since html is a static resource it makes sense to work like this. Thank you!